# Knockout switches template between forEach and data

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want a dynamic container to show all of my content, so I have a model like this:

```
function ContentViewmodel() {
        var engines = ko.observableArray(),
            application = ko.observable({ name: 'luna-content-engines', foreach: engines });

        function registerEngine(engine) {
            engines.push(engine);
        }

        function showConsoleContent() {
            application({ name: 'luna-console-template' });
        }

        function showEngineContent() {
            application({ name: 'luna-content-engines', foreach: engines });
        }

        return {
            registerEngine: registerEngine,
            engines: engines,
            showConsoleContent: showConsoleContent,
            showEngineContent: showEngineContent,
            application: application
        };

<div id="luna-content-container" data-bind="template: content"></div>
    <script type="text/html" id="luna-content">
        <div class="luna-content-menu">
            <div class="luna-content-menu-item" data-bind="click: showEngineContent">Engines</div>
            <div class="luna-content-menu-item" data-bind="click: showConsoleContent">Console</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="luna-content-engines-container" data-bind="template: application"></div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

If I switch from default to content it works perfectly, but switching back to engines, with forEach doesn't work; if I change it back to normal data, it works again.

Maybe I do something wrong with the object binding. Any suggestion, even with a complete different approach?

Comment: can u get us a fiddle with complete code in it .

Comment: It might just be down to the way you pasted the text into your question, but your `ContentViewModel` function isn't closed.   Also, is that `template` binding correct? The Knockout docs show that it takes an object, not a string.

Comment: Where do you see a string? and yes its how i pasted in that code.